# Build Qt static from source enabling OpenSSL support

Tags: c++, qt, ssl, static

I followed the instructions for the Qt static build as described in https://wiki.qt.io/Building_a_static_Qt_for_Windows_using_MinGW. Running the script on my Windows 10 machine just works fine and builds Qt statically. However, since I require OpenSSL support I can not compile my program with the static build produced from the `.ps`script.

Therefore, I slightly changed the `configure.bat` options of the `.ps` script from `-no-openssl` to

```
-openssl-linked 
-I C:\OpenSSL-Win32\include 
-L C:\OpenSSL-Win32\lib\VC\static 
OPENSSL_LIBS="-lUser32 -lAdvapi32 -lGdi32 -lCrypt32"             
OPENSSL_LIBS_DEBUG=-"lssleay32MTd -llibeay32MTd" 
OPENSSL_LIBS_RELEASE="-lssleay32MT -llibeay32MT
```

to enable OpenSSL support in a static Qt build, based on the anwseres from:

[QT https SSL support for static QT static program build - getting 'Protocol "https" is unknown'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35442599/qt-https-ssl-support-for-static-qt-static-program-build-getting-protocol-htt)

and

[Is there any way to building static Qt with static OpenSSL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20843180/is-there-any-way-to-building-static-qt-with-static-openssl)

Running the script now produces not further specified errors in the make install steps. The `-lUser32 -lAdvapi32 -lGdi32 -lCrypt32` libs are not in any subfolder of my OpenSSL-Win32 installation but can be found in `C:\Windows\System32\`.

Comment: If you just remove `-no-openssl` it will revert to the default, which is use the platform provided SSL

Answer (score 0):

I interpret the question as:

> How can I build Qt static from source enabling OpenSSL support at the
>   project installation target?

One of possible ways is:

- Static Qt build: `configure -static -debug-and-release -openssl -I %OPENSSL_HOME%\include -L %OPENSSL_HOME%` and more options
- Link the project executable with same SSL at %OPENSSL_HOME%
- Distribute the corresponding libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll altogether with the rest of executables