# Compile static version of QT + OpenSSL Support

Tags: qt, static, compilation, openssl

I have downloaded source files of qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0 from here: https://download.qt.io/snapshots/qt/5.8/5.8.0/latest_src/

I want to compile it with support for Static version of QT + OpenSSL

I have installed QtFramework(qt-opensource-windows-x86-mingw530-5.8.0) and Win32 OpenSSL v1.0.2k downloaded from here: https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html

What arguments need?

[image]

Comment: [QT https SSL support for static QT static program build](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35442599/608639) on Stack Overflow, [Adding OpenSSL Support](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/opensslsupport.html) in the Qt Documentation? and [Static build of Qt, Qt5Network linking error](https://forum.qt.io/topic/54782/static-build-of-qt-qt5network-linking-error) on the Qt Forums?

Comment: @jww    
Try the following configuration: `-static -release -platform win32-g++ -openssl-linked -I C:/OpenSSL-Win32/include -L C:/OpenSSL-Win32/lib OPENSSL_LIBS="-llibeay32 -lssleay32 -lgdi32"` error :https://s29.postimg.org/o8rmli63b/image.jpg

Comment: Also see [Is there any way to building static Qt with static OpenSSL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20843180/608639).