# How to static compile Qt 5.9.1 with OpenSSL?

Tags: qt, static, compilation, openssl

I have `qt-opensource-windows-x86-5.9.1.exe`, `qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.9.1` and `openssl-win32 1.0.2l` installed. I want to do the statically compilation with `qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.9.1` and activate OpenSSL for this I use this script.

Please what is the modification of this part of the script that a i need to do for that (line breaks added for readability):

```
configure.bat -static -release -platform win32-g++ -prefix %QtStaticDir% -qt-zlib -qt-pcre
-qt-libpng -qt-libjpeg -qt-freetype -opengl desktop -sql-odbc -sql-sqlite -no-openssl
-opensource -confirm-license -make libs -nomake tools -nomake examples -nomake tests"
```

Thanks

Comment: What kind of problem with that? If no problem then build with `jom` on Windows from the root of Qt source code. The compiler needs to be set up.

Comment: `-no-openssl` looks suspicious. I think you are supposed to use `-openssl-linked`. Also see [Is there any way to building static Qt with static OpenSSL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20843180/608639) and [Compile static version of QT + OpenSSL Support](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41938379/608639).